# Instantaneous power consumption value

Tags: energy

If, for a large motor, you are given cumulative kWh values at 5-minute increments, how would you determine an instantaneous power consumption value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine **average** power consumption (kW) because it is kWh divided by hours.

Instantaneous power varies wih the cyclic nature of the voltage (v) and current (i) waveforms and, the instantaneous product of v and i is "averaged" in order to determine **average** power from which kWh is derived.

Note also that for many AC systems, the phase angle between v and i is important to consider: -

[image]

But, you can't assume the load is purely linear and, because of this, the instantaneous power may be very much higher in certain places than the **average** power value would imply.